# Only isolated critical points can be asintotically stable.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For an equation of the form $\dot{x}=f(x)$ I'm asked to prove that is not possible for a not isolated critical point $a$ be asintotically stable. Is this statement wrong? Because what it asks not only doesn't seem true, but it seems to me that the opposite always happens.

The definitons:

$(1)$ If $a$ is isolated then $B_{\epsilon}^*(a)$ has no critical points for every $\epsilon>0$.

$(2)$ If $a$ is stable, besides the conditions for stability $a$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=a$. This is to say, given $\epsilon >0$ there's a $T>0$ such that $t>T\implies d(x(t),a)<\epsilon$.

Then under this conditions, I would have to prove that given $\epsilon >0$ and $T$ exists $t>T$ such that $d(x(t),a)\geq \epsilon$. But I can't see a relation between this fact and that for every $r$ the ball $B_r(a)$  always contains critical points.

My idea was to do it by absurdum, what if $a$ is asintotically stable and how this contradicts the existence of critical points? It feels like the solutions would get "swallowed" in the critical points near $a$, making in it unable to be asymptotically stable? (very vague, I know...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Any epsilon neighborhood of your equilibrium has other equilibria. Start your orbit at one of them. What will happen?

Comment: In the case of an equilibria stable or asymptotically stable, the orbit would remain around this other point making it impossible to remain eventually around $a$, needed to make it asymptotically stable?
But what is the equilibria is unstable?, can I use the same argument?

Comment: @Cure You did not read my hint.

Comment: @Cure Thank you for accepting my answer, but the question still stands: did you now get my hint?

Comment: Yes, after a while I got it, that's why accepted the answer. Should I update my initial post with the solution to the problem?

Comment: No, you should not :)